# In Gaussian elimination, can you divide a row by a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&0\\3&0\end{bmatrix}

I am trying to use Gaussian elimination to get reduced row echelon form but I'm not sure whether my steps are correct. This is what I did:

\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&0\\3&0\end{bmatrix}
-> \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
-> \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
-> \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}
-> \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\0&-2\\0&0\end{bmatrix}

At this point, can I just divide row 2 by -2 to get a nice 1 over there? is that allowed?

Comment: You already used that operation twice, for instance in your very first operation you divided row 3 by 3 to get a nice 1 in the lower left corner.

Comment: No, I just did R3-R2. Then I did R2 - R3. Then I did R3 - R2. Then I did R2-R1.

Comment: Yes you can; it is the same as multiplication of the row by -1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is totally legal. Recall that you can multiply by a scalar. In the context of dividing by a scalar you are really just multiplying by some scalar 1/n

Comment: no this is unnecessary, unless you want to to demonstrate and show your work for your own steps. Also, you are also allowed to just get rid of that bottom row so you  have a 2x2 matrix